# How do I show that $\frac{1}{\pi^2}<\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^3}\ dx<\frac{3}{2 \pi^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, derivatives

I started by trying to pick functions $f(x)\le  \frac{\sin(x)}{x^3}\le g(x).$

And I got this,

let $F'=f$ and $G'=g$

we need $f$ and $g$,
$s.t.$ $F(\pi)-F(\pi/2)=1/\pi^2$ and $G(\pi)-G(\pi/2)=3/2\pi^2$.

I got stuck here.

Comment: What sort of upper bounds do you know for $\sin x$? E.g., $\sin x \leq x$ and $\sin x \leq 1$: have you tried either? (one of them will work for the upper bound).

Comment: maybe it is between ∫sin(x)/x²dx and ∫sin(x)/x^4 dx and this integrals are solvable

Comment: $\dfrac{\sin x}{x^3} \leq \dfrac{1}{x^3}$.

Comment: by the way maybe you can solve the integral by partial integration - split  on 1/x and sin(x)/x²

Comment: For the lower bound, $\sin$ is concave then : $$\forall x \in \left[\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right], \sin x \geq 2 - \dfrac{2}{\pi}$$